# No value given for one or more required parameters vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Hi all Iam trying to reduce a stock using this code below but Iam getting error, can any one help me pleaseee????`

```
Public Sub UpdateDecreaseQuantity()
    Try
        Dim cb As String = "Update Dish SET Quantity = stocksOnHand - '" & DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value & "' "
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(cb, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly,** If `DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value` is `0` length string or `Nothing` value you will get this error.

Please check using:
`Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value)`.

**Secondly,** you have added quotes around the Cell value in the query

> '" & DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value & "' "

Numeric value should not have quotes around.

**Thirdly,** this query is prone to SQL injection attack. Please try to parameterize the query.

*Example:*

```
Dim OtherValue as Integer = 0
Dim cb As String = "Update Dish SET Quantity = stocksOnHand - @OtherValue"
con.Open()
cmd = New OleDbCommand(cb, con)
Int32.TryParse(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value, OtherValue)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OtherValue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OtherValue
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to parameterize the query of code please?

Comment: Hi @Sunil i did some updated on code according your suggestion but when i run my application NOTHING happen ( no error, and no work)

Answer (score 0):

Just as you use double quotes to signify a `String` in VB but do not put them around numbers, so single quotes denote a string in SQL.  If you are subtracting two numbers then they must both be numbers, not a one number and a string.

```
Dim cb As String = "Update Dish SET Quantity = stocksOnHand - " & DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
```

Even better would be to learn how to insert values into SQL properly and use parameters.